# bdist_wheel creates py37 wheel instead of py36

Tags: python, python-wheel

In order to generate a pip wheel of sagemaker-training repository [https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit.git]

I ran

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

It results in creation of python 37 compatible wheel

```
ls dist/
sagemaker_training-3.6.3.dev0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I checked the `setup.py`; it doesn't specifically mention py37.

Is there a way to create a binary [pip wheel] that's compatible with python36?

#### Why do I need py36 compatible binary?

Because py36 can't consume py37 wheel

```
RUN pip3 install sagemaker_training-3.6.3.dev0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
 ---> Running in ca56241af5fa
ERROR: sagemaker_training-3.6.3.dev0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **the wheel is compatible with the invoking Python interpreter**, that is, you're probably have installed Python 3.7, you can quickly verify this by running `which python`.

### Solution

Consider [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), as example I'll be using python 3.6.1

```
pyenv install 3.6.1
```

you could verify the installation by running

```
ls ~/.pyenv/versions/
```

and set the installed version as [global](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-global) or local (for the purposes of this example I'll be setting it as global).

```
pyenv global 3.6.1
```

if you want you could verify this with

```
python -V
```

Finally, you can create a wheel compatible with Python3.6.

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

### References

1. Intro to Pyenv (Real Python). URL: https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

Comment: instead is there a way to build py36 version of binary?

Comment: To build py36 version of binary, I used `virtualenv` instead of `pyenv` but yes the logic is similar. Thanks!

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat nice!, I didn't know that. Perhaps you could do a little edit to the question.

Comment: sure what edit to the question are you referring to? feel free to go ahead and edit it.. :)